# Jquery autocomplete not updating

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I'm making an AJAX call to populate an input field with an Autocomplete. This autocomplete is not being updated, however the JSON response is being generated correctly, the problem is that the results of the autocomplete are not being updated. Something strange is that the autocomplete works on localhost, but when I try to do it on the web server, it doesn't work. Below is the code:

```
<input name="Label" class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input ui-autocomplete-loading" type="text" id="Label" autocomplete="off">
```

Here is the Javascript of the autocomplete:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#Label').autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        source: function(request, response){
            var loadTitles = "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'Titles', 'action' => 'getAjax'))?>/" + request.term;
            $.getJSON(loadTitles, function(data){
                response(data);
            });
        },
        focus: function(event, ui){
            $('#Label').val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui){
            $('#Label').val(ui.item.label);
            $('#Label').val(ui.item.id);
            return false;
        }
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ){
        return $( "<li>" )
            .append( "<a>" + item.label + " [<strong>" + item.description + "</strong>]</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };

});
```

As I mentioned earlier, the AJAX function is working correctly (getAjax function), it is implemented on CakePHP framework, and is returning the JSON result correctly, the problem is that the input autocomplete is not rendering the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggling I found the issue. The problem was that a value on the JSON had a lot of white spaces at the end of it, so the following function gave an unexpected token error:

```
$.getJSON(loadTitles, function(data){
   response(data);
 });
```

I added the .fail function to it, and I received the unexpected token error with white spaces.

Another problem is that I was using Chrome, and it use some kind of trim to get rid of white spaces, so I couldn't see it. I tried to debug on Firefox, using the Firebug plugin, and in that browser I was able to see the white spaces on one of the JSON elements. I deleted the white spaces on the database, and the autocomplete started working like a charm.